# How to control the output of fileno?

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I'm facing a piece of code that I don't understand:

```
read(fileno(stdin),&i,1);
switch(i)
{
    case '\n':
      printf("\a");
      break;
    ....
```

I know that `fileno` return the file descriptor associated with the `sdtin` here, then `read` put this value in `i` variable.

So, what should be the value of `stdin` to allow `i` to match with the first "case", i.e `\n` ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what the `read` function does? Think of the `read` call in the shown code as a simple way to do an unbuffered `getchar` or `getc` or `fgetc` from `stdin`. Would your question make sense then, if it was e.g. `getchar` that was used instead of `read`?

Comment: Sorry I just updated my post

Comment: The type of  `i` must be `char` (or `signed char` or `unsigned char`), and the next byte unread in the input must be a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that `fileno` return the file descriptor associated with the `sdtin` here,

Yes, though I suspect you don't know what that means.

> then `read` put this value in `i` variable.

No.  No no no no no.  `read()` *does not* put the value of the file descriptor, or any part of it, into the provided buffer (in your case, the bytes of `i`).  As its name suggests, `read()` attempts to **read from *the file*** represented by the file descriptor passed as its first argument.  The bytes read, if any, are stored in the provided buffer.

`stdin` represents the program's standard input.  If you run the program from an interactive shell, that will correspond to your keyboard.  The program attempts to read user input, and to compare it with a newline.

The program is likely flawed, and maybe outright wrong, though it's impossible to tell from just the fragment presented.  If `i` is a variable of type `int` then its representation is larger than one byte, but you're only reading one byte into it.  That will replace only one byte of the representation, with results depending on C implementation and the data read.

What the program seems to be trying to do can be made to work with `read()`, but I would recommend using `getchar()` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
...
int i;
...
*/

i = getchar();

/* ... */
```

Answer (score 2):

> But what should be the value of stdin to match with the first "case", i.e \n ?

The case statement doesn't look at the "value" of stdin.

```
 read(fileno(stdin),&i,1);
```

reads in a single byte into `i` (assuming `read()` call is successful) and if that byte is `\n` (newline character) then it'll match the case. You probably need to read the man page of [`read(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) to understand what it does.

Comment: `stdin` is a file pointer; `fileno` call provides its file descriptor value which is `0` (the macro `STDIN_FILENO`, defined in `<unistd.h>` represents the same). So, read call is equivalent to: `read(0, &i, 1);` which reads a single byte. Not sure how `stdin` is directly connected to the case statement. It's essentially reading one byte from standard input and checking if it's `\n` (newline).

Comment: this code is valid, so there must be a case where int("\n") must be the value of a file descriptor

Comment: @HolyGraal:  I'm not sure your last comment makes sense.  `int("\n")` is not meaningful C code; it is semi-meaningful in C++, but not sensible practice and doesn't mean what you'd want it to mean.